# How to fix 'Error in .ValidateHolidayList(holiday.list)' in bsts package R?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

When specifying custom holidays in the `bsts` R package, I get the error

```
Error " .ValidateHolidayList(holiday.list) : all(sapply(holiday.list, inherits, "Holiday")) is not TRUE "
```

Same issue with the example in the `vignette`.

How can I create a valid Holiday object ?

```
head(data)
A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date         tot
  <date>     <int>
1 2019-01-07   143
2 2019-01-08   133
3 2019-01-09   178
4 2019-01-10   140
5 2019-01-11   175
6 2019-01-12   255

 holiday.name = "school_holidays"
 start.date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-04-08", "2019-07-01"))
 end.date = as.Date(c("2019-01-06", "2019-03-10", "2019-04-22", "2019-08-05"))

 holidays = DateRangeHoliday(holiday.name,
                             start.date,
                             end.date)

 ss = AddRegressionHoliday(list(), data$tot, holiday.list = holidays)
Error in .ValidateHolidayList(holiday.list) : 
  all(sapply(holiday.list, inherits, "Holiday")) is not TRUE
```

Comment: What if you try: `holiday.list = list(holidays)`?

Comment: yes, it was as simple as that. Thx mate